# Como obter um único objeto a partir da comparação do menor dos valores entre um array de objetos?

Tags: javascript, json, array, objetos

Não estou conseguindo fazer uma seleção que busque qual é menor preço e também o menor prazo de entrega de um JSON.

Preciso retornar o objeto completo. Algo como:

```
{
  id: 2,
  price: 10,
  available: true,
  delivery_time: 7
}
```

Mas o meu código atual retorna somente os valores:

```js
let response = [
  { id: 1, price: 10, available: true, delivery_time: 20 },
  { id: 2, price: 10, available: true, delivery_time: 7 },
  { id: 3, price: 30, available: true, delivery_time: 5 },
  { id: 4, price: 40, available: true, delivery_time: 1 }
];

let a = response.map(function (v) {
  return v.price;
});
let b = response.map(function (v) {
  return v.delivery_time;
});

let aa = Math.min.apply(null, a);
let bb = Math.min.apply(null, b);

console.log(aa);
console.log(bb);
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que, ao aplicar `Math.min` ao resultado do mapeamento do array original aos preços e tempos de entrega, você perde a referência para o objeto desejado. Nessa situação, embora você tenha o **valor** do menor preço e do menor tempo de entrega, você não possui referência ao objeto a qual eles ora já pertenceram.

Portanto, você deve procurar um meio de manter a referência aos objetos. Para isso, você pode utilizar um `for` para iterar sobre cada objeto, criando dois objetos (externos ao `for`) para armazenar qual é o item de menor preço e o item de menor tempo de entrega.

A medida que o laço for fazendo as iterações, você verifica se o atual satisfaz os critérios melhor que o anterior e, se positivo, altera o objeto de "referência".

Algo assim:

```js
const response = [
  { id: 1, price: 10, available: true, delivery_time: 20 },
  { id: 2, price: 10, available: true, delivery_time: 7 },
  { id: 3, price: 30, available: true, delivery_time: 5 },
  { id: 4, price: 40, available: true, delivery_time: 1 }
];

let minPrice = response[0];
let minDeliveryTime = response[0];

// Como já começamos no primeiro elemento da lista, podemos começar a iterar
// a partir do segundo (índice 1):
for (let i = 1; i < response.length; i++) {
  const current = response[i];

  // Se o preço for menor que o atual, substituimos:
  if (current.price < minPrice.price) {
    minPrice = current;
  }

  // Se o tempo de entrega for menor que o atual, substituimos:
  if (current.delivery_time < minDeliveryTime.delivery_time) {
    minDeliveryTime = current;
  }
}

console.log(minPrice);
console.log(minDeliveryTime);
```

Provavelmente tem como encapsular isso em uma função relativamente genérica, mas deixo como desafio. Se tiver tempo hábil, acrescento aqui depois. :-)

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado mesmo pelo auxilio. Vou buscar resolver este desafio kk

Comment: De nada, @VHB. Veja no [tour] como agradecer por aqui. Pode aceitar a resposta e votar positivo, se achar pertinente. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Recebe as opções de frete disponiveis  
const frete_opcoes = [
  { id: 1, price: 10, available: true, delivery_time: 8 },
  { id: 2, price: 10, available: true, delivery_time: 7 },
  { id: 3, price: 30, available: true, delivery_time: 5 },
  { id: 4, price: 40, available: true, delivery_time: 1 }
];
// Filtra pelo menor preço
let menor_preco = frete_opcoes[0];
for (let i = 1; i < frete_opcoes.length; i++) {
const atual = frete_opcoes[i];
  // Se o preço for menor que o atual, substituimos:
  if (atual.price < menor_preco.price) {
    menor_preco = atual;
  }

}
var menortempo = frete_opcoes.filter(function(envio) {
  var preco = Number(envio.price);
  return preco <= menor_preco.price;
});

let MelhorFrete = menortempo[0];
for (let i = 1; i < menortempo.length; i++) {
  const selecionaAtual = menortempo[i];
  if (selecionaAtual.delivery_time < MelhorFrete.delivery_time) {
    MelhorFrete = selecionaAtual;
  }

}
console.log(MelhorFrete);
```